# URL can i specify zoom in or focus

Tags: javascript, html, url

i have a url something like this: www.mysite.com/login.html and when the user clicks it they obvivously head to a login page.  This is occur on a mobile device but the end point is not a mobile web site yet.  I'd like to be able to set focus on the user name field and even zoom on the entire page if possible.  What are my options to do this from the url itself as i don't have access to the website backend yet. Its on iphone but that should make no difference.

i wish i could do www.mysite.com/login.html?zoomin  or www.mysite.com/login.html#focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this HTML tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Your page will resize to the device size.

Comment: does that go in the header ? because i said i dont have access to the backend server unfortunately

Comment: in the head of you'r html page yes